# How do I set up a MySql Connection in Play 2.6 for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm a newbie at this, and try as I might I am unable to find a full example of how to configure a Scala Play 2.6 application. There are obvious difference between versions of Play and the 2.6 documentaion doesn't have a full example.

My current state is I'm getting a ataSource or *dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.* error.

Also, can someone explain the purpose of the two "db" sections in application.conf,
play.db{} vs. db{}

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Slick`you can config it like this:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://url:3306/dbname"
        user = "user"
        password = "password"

        // comment out for Production
        connectionPool = disabled
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using evolutions then you have to add following line to your config:

`play.evolutions.enabled = true`

The evolution .sql-files for your default DB config need to be placed in

`conf/evolutions/default/`

A Class with some DB stuff needs following imports and injections:

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

@Singleton
class DBClass @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] { 

    import profile.api._
...
}
```

A Controller would look similar:

```
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}
import slick.jdbc.{JdbcProfile, TransactionIsolation}

@Singleton
class DBController @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, 
cc: ControllerComponents)
      extends AbstractController(cc) with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

    import profile.api._
...
}
```

For implicit Execution Context you would need to this import:

`import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

For further reading of slick check this book out:

https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, the following isn't throwing any exceptions:

In build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jdbc,  ehcache , ws , specs2 % Test , guice )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.11")
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36")
```

In application.conf

```
db.default.driver   = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database"
db.default.username = "my_user_name"
db.default.password = "my_password"
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }
}
```